# How do I count the number of elements in my array that are unique and are bigger than the element before them?

Tags: arrays, ruby, count

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings taht are all numbers.  I want to count the number of elements in the array that are unique and that are also greater than the element before them (I consider the first array element already greater than its non-existent predecessor).  So I tried

```
data_col = ["3", "6", "10"]
 #=> ["3", "6", "10"] 
data_col.map { |string| string.to_i.to_s == string ? string.to_i : -2 }.each_cons(2).select { |a, b| a > b && data_col.count(a) == 1 }.count
 #=> 0
```

but the results is zero, despite the fact that all the elements in my array satisfy my criteria.  How can I improve the way I count this?

Comment: It would have been clearer to have said, "I want to count the number of elements (numbers) `n` in the array such that that `n` is unique and is either the first element of the array or is greater than the previous element of the array after both have been converted to integers." It might have been better for `data_col` to have been integers rather than strings, as converting them to integers (and possibly back to strings) is just a nuisance calculation, not the essence of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. `a > b` seems like the opposite of what you want to test. That should probably be `b > a`.
2. If I followed properly, I think `data_col.count(a)` is always going to be zero, since `a` is an integer and `data_col` contains only strings. Also, I'm not sure you want to be looking for `a`... `b` is probably the right element to look for.
3. I'm not sure you're ever counting the first element here. (You said you consider the first element to be greater than its non-existent predecessor, but where in your code does that happen?)

Here's some code that works:

```
def foo(x)
    ([nil] + x).each_cons(2).select { |a, b| (a == nil or b > a) and x.count(b) == 1 }.count()
end

p foo([3, 6, 10])  # 3
p foo([3, 6, 10, 1, 6])  # 2
```

(If you have an array of strings, feel free to do `.map { |s| s.to_i }` first.)

Comment: Your solution is O(n^2) time-complexity, where n is the size of the array. That because count is done for each increasing element in the array. A single pass through the array is sufficient. @Ilya's solution is similar, but by obtaining the counts as an initial step he's kept the complexity to O(n).

Comment: Oh, definitely. I was just trying to make a minimal edit to the original code.

Comment: Not really a serious suggestion, but if you wrote `([x.first-0.5] + x)` rather than `([nil]+x)`, `(a == nil or b > a)` could be simplified to `b > a`.

Comment: I think Ruby defines an infinity? Might be even better.

Comment: Yes, `-Float::INFINITY => -Infinity` (or the shorthand `-1/0.0`, which I don't think is oft used).

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'set'

 def nbr_uniq_and_bigger(arr)   
  processed = Set.new
  arr.each_cons(2).with_object(Set.new) do |(n,m),keepers|
    if processed.add?(m)
      keepers << m if m > n
    else
      keepers.delete(m)
    end
  end.size + (processed.include?(arr.first) ? 0 : 1)
end

nbr_uniq_and_bigger [1, 2, 6, 3, 2]
  #=> 2
nbr_uniq_and_bigger [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
  #=> 0
```

See [Set.add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F).

Note the line `keepers.delete(m)` could be written

```
keepers.delete(m) if keepers.key(m)
```

but attempting to delete an element not in the set does not harm.

Comment: I like how you are using the right tools for problems - nice solution!

Comment: @Ilya nice catch about uniqueness, I did not get your comment from the first time

Comment: @Ilya, fixed, I think.

Comment: The first example should return 2, not 1.

Comment: @Eric, `6 > 2` is one. What's the other?

Comment: `I consider the first array element already greater than its non-existent predecessor`

Comment: My pleasure. You know I like heckling :)

Comment: ...and I like being heckled (@Eric). :-)

Answer (score 1):

One more solution:

```
def uniq_and_bigger(data)
  counts = data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 } #precalculate

  data.each_cons(2).with_object([]) do |(n,m), a|
    a << m if m > n && counts[m] == 1
  end.size + (counts[data[0]] == 1 ? 1 : 0)
end

uniq_and_bigger([3, 6, 10, 1, 6])
=> 2
uniq_and_bigger([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
=> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. It's `O(n)` and it returns the desired result for `[3, 6, 10]`.

It uses [`slice_when`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) :

```
def unique_and_increasing(array)
  duplicates = array.group_by(&:itself).select{ |_, v| v.size > 1 }.keys
  (array.slice_when{ |a, b| a < b }.map(&:first) - duplicates).size
end

p unique_and_increasing [3, 6, 10]
# 3
p unique_and_increasing [3, 6, 10, 1, 6]
# 2
p unique_and_increasing [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
# 0
```